# C++ : recognizing lower case as correct when its stored as upper case?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, case

I have a 1d array of correct answers, but they are stored as upper case in the txt file. I want to take in a users input, but if he answers lower case i want the program to accept his answer as lower or upper case.  am i on the right track? also, my test if its a valid response (a-d or A-D) didnt work.. is there something else i could try?

```
char answers[x];
cin >> user_guess;

while (user_guess != "a" || "b" || "c" || "d" || "A" || "B" || "C" || "D") //doesnt work?
{
cout<< "Please correctly identify your answer." << endl;
cin >> user_guess;
}

if (islower (user_guess) )
{
toupper (user_guess) )
}
if (user_guess != answers[x])
{
cout << "incorrect! << endl;
}
else
{
cout << "correct!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test for a correct choice doesn't work because that's not how `||` works. What you need is something like:

```
while (user_guess != "a" && user_guess != "b" && user_guess != "c" && user_guess != "d"
       user_guess != "A" && user_guess != "B" && user_guess != "C" && user_guess != "D") {
```

Also, there's no harm in calling `toupper()` on something that isn't a lower case character. So you can just do:

```
if (toupper(user_guess) != answers[x]) {
```

If you convert `user_guess` to upper case right after you read it in from `cin`, then you can both shorten the "valid guess" test (by only having to test against uppercase answers), and omit the `toupper()` from the test against `answers[x]`.

Comment: Suggestion – after converting `user_guess` to uppercase, do a range check instead of comparing to every single letter: `while (!(user_guess >= 'A' && user_guess <= 'D'))`

Comment: IMO better to convert to lower case using `tolower` and then `switch` on the result with only four labels